# Trouble with javascript, protractor, and classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I'm having some trouble understanding class scope and how to utilize objects, prototypes, etc, within the system I'm having.  It seems to me that I'm doing things correctly, but it isn't working and I'm hoping someone can explain it to me or get me pointed in the right direction.

So here's the situation:
I'm trying to create a generic page object and verification object that would handle an input box with an associated text label.  Things do appear to work if I have the verification in the same class as the page object structure, but I've recently learned that is bad design.

This is an Angular 2 rc1 site.  I'm using protractor 3.3.0 and have ensured that the project version of selenium and chromedriver are up-to-date by using webdriver-manager.

So here's what I've done (filenames are in the comments at the start of each section):

```
'use strict';

/*
 * InputLabelPageObject.js
 *
 * This object will provide basic methods for an Input box with an attached label.
 * It is expected that the label will have an element called "label" and an element called "input"
 */

module.exports = InputLabelPageObject;

/**
 * Create an object that will provide methods for an input/label combination of elements.
 *
 * @param container The selector for the __container of the input/label combination of elements.
 */
function InputLabelPageObject(container) {
    this.Container = container;
}

InputLabelPageObject.prototype = {
    constructor: InputLabelPageObject,
    /**
     * Return the element for the label of the input/label combination of elements.
     *
     * @returns {protractor.element}
     */
    getLabel: function () {
        return this.Container.$('label');
    },
    /**
     * Return the element for the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     *
     * @returns {ElementFinder}
     */
    getInput: function () {
        return this.Container.$('input');
    },
    /**
     * Return the text shown in the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     *
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    getValue: function () {
        return this.getInput().getAttribute('value');
    },
    /**
     * Get the placeholder text shown in the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     *
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    getPlaceholder: function () {
        return this.getInput().getAttribute('placeholder');
    },
    /**
     * Clears the input element then puts the text from data into the input element.
     *
     * @param data The text to be entered into the input element.
     */
    sendKeys: function (data) {
        var el = this.getInput();
        el.clear().then(function () {
            return el.sendKeys(data);
        });
    }
};
```

--

```
'use strict';

/*
 * InputLabelVerification.js
 *
 * Provide verification methods associated with an Input and Label 
 * combination of elements.
 */

module.exports = InputLabelVerifications;

var inputLabelPageObject;

function InputLabelVerifications(inputLabelPageObject) {
    this.__setPageObject(inputLabelPageObject);
}

InputLabelVerifications.prototype = {
    constructor: InputLabelVerifications,
    __setPageObject: function (ilpo) {
        inputLabelPageObject = ilpo;
    },
    /**
     * Verify the text on the label of the input/label combination of elements.
     *
     * @param expected The expected text on the label.
     */
    verifyText: function (expected) {
        //console.log('Asserting text [' + expected + ']');
        expect(inputLabelPageObject.getLabel()).toEqual(expected);
    },
    /**
     * Verify the text shown in the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     *
     * @param expected The expected text in the input element.
     */
    verifyValue: function (expected) {
        //console.log('Asserting input value [' + expected + ']');
        expect(inputLabelPageObject.getValue()).toEqual(expected);
    },
    /**
     * Verify the placeholder text shown in the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     *
     * @param expected The expected text of the placeholder.
     */
    verifyPlaceholder: function (expected) {
        //console.log('Verifying placeholder text [' + expected + ']');
        expect(inputLabelPageObject.getPlaceholder()).toEqual(expected);
    }
};
```

--

```
'use strict';

/*
 * LoginPageObject.js
 *
 */

var InputLabelPageObject = require('./generics/InputLabelPageObject.js');

module.exports = LoginPageObject;

var __container = $('login-component');
var username = new InputLabelPageObject(__container.$('form:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)'));
var password = new InputLabelPageObject(__container.$('form:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)'));

/**
 * Create an object that contains the methods necessary to perform actions against the LoginPageObject page.
 *
 * @param url The base URL string. If not undefined, it will load the url+'/login' page.
 * @constructor new LoginPageObject('http://localhost:9000');
 */
function LoginPageObject(url) {
    if (url) {
        this.loadPage(url)
    }
}

LoginPageObject.prototype = {
    constructor: LoginPageObject,
    loadPage: function (url) {
        url = url + '/login';
        console.log('Loading page: '+ url);
        browser.get(url);
    },
    welcome: {
        /**
         * Return the element for the Welcome text
         *
         * @returns {ElementFinder}
         */
        get: function () {
            return __container.$('section:first-child h1:first-child');
        },
    },
    /**
     * Return an InputLabelPageObject object specific for the username input and label elements.
     */
    username: username,
    /**
     * Return an InputLabelPageObject object specific for the password input and label elements.
     */
    password: password,
    loginButton: {
        /**
         * Return the element for the login button.
         *
         * @returns {ElementFinder}
         */
        get: function () {
            return __container.$('form > button');
        },
        /**
         * Click the LoginPageObject button.
         * @returns {*|void|webdriver.promise.Promise<void>|ActionSequence|!webdriver.promise.Promise.<void>}
         */
        click: function () {
            return this.get().click();
        }
    }
};
```

--

```
'use strict';

/*
 * LoginPageVerifications.js
 */

var LoginPageObject = require('../pageObjects/LoginPageObject');
var verifyText = require('./generics/VerifyText');
var inputLabelVerifications = require('./generics/InputLabelVerifications');

module.exports = LoginPageVerifications;

var __loginPageObject = new LoginPageObject();

function LoginPageVerifications(url) {
    if (url) {
        __loginPageObject = new LoginPageObject(url);
    }
}

LoginPageVerifications.prototype = {
    constructor: LoginPageVerifications,
    loginPageObject: new LoginPageObject(),
    welcome: {
        verifyText: function (expected) {
            verifyText(__loginPageObject.welcome.get(), expected);
        }
    },
    username: new inputLabelVerifications(__loginPageObject.username),
    password: new inputLabelVerifications(__loginPageObject.password),
    loginButton: {
        verifyText: function (expected) {
            verifyText(__loginPageObject.loginButton.get(), expected);
        }
    },
    /**
     * Performs the actions of logging in. That is, enter the username and password values,
     * then click the LoginPageObject button. This does *not* verify page load.
     *
     * @param username The username to login with.
     * @param password The password to login with.
     */
    doLogin: function (username, password) {
        var uPromise = __loginPageObject.username.sendKeys(username);
        var pPromise = __loginPageObject.password.sendKeys(password);
        protractor.promise.asap(this.username.verifyValue(username));
        protractor.promise.asap(this.password.verifyValue(password));
        protractor.promise.all([uPromise, pPromise]).then(this.loginButton.click());
    },
    /**
     * Verifies all page elements' text or other default attributes.
     *
     * @param welcomeText The expected Welcome text
     * @param userText The expected username label text.
     * @param userPlaceholder The expected username's input element's placeholder text.
     * @param passText The expected password label text.
     * @param passPlaceholder The expected password's input element's placeholder text.
     * @param loginText The expected login button text.
     */
    verifyPage: function (welcomeText, userText, userPlaceholder, passText, passPlaceholder, loginText) {
        this.welcome.verifyText(welcomeText);
        this.username.verifyText(userText);
        this.username.verifyPlaceholder(userPlaceholder);
        this.password.verifyText(passText);
        this.password.verifyPlaceholder(passPlaceholder);
        this.loginButton.verifyText(loginText);
    }

};
```

--

```
'use strict';

/*
 * login-spec.js
 */

var LoginPageVerifications = require('../components/actions/LoginPageVerifications');

var myUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

describe('My Login Page test', function() {
   var loginPage;
   beforeAll(function() {
       loginPage = new LoginPageVerifications(myUrl);
   });

   it('should verify username input and label values', function() {
       var welcomeText = 'Thank you for visiting my login page';
       var userText = 'Username';
       var userPlaceholder = 'Enter your username';
       var passText = 'Password';
       var passPlaceholder = 'Enter your password';
       var loginText = 'Login';

       loginPage.username.verifyText(userText);
       // loginPage.verifyPage(welcomeText, userText, userPlaceholder, passText, passPlaceholder, loginText);
   });
});
```

The results that I'm usually seeing:
If in InputLabelVerification.js I leave out `var inputLabelPageObject` or try to set the value only in the constructor function, I get `Failed: Cannot read property 'getLabel' of undefined`. So, I've figured that I must set it the way I have it shown above.

The closest I seem to get is when I get the following response:

```
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
F

Failures:
1) My Login Page test should verify username input and label values
Expected ({ ptor_: ({ controlFlow: Function, schedule: Function, 
setFileDetector: Function, getSession: Function, getCapabilities: Function, 
quit: Function, actions: Function, touchActions: Function, 
executeScript: Function, executeAsyncScript: Function, call: Function, 
wait: Function, sleep: Function, getWindowHandle... }) }) to equal 'Username'.
```

In the LoginPageVerification.js, I've tested and ensured that the other verifications (welcome and loginButton) work fine.

Also, if from login-spec.js I add this line:

```
expect(loginPage.loginPageObject.username.getLabel().getText()).toEqual(userText);
```

this expect passes the test.

Comment: I've got the answer. And now I feel silly. I'll post as the answer when I can in 2 days. (This only took me several days to get it right.) Essentially, I'm calling `.getLabel()` from the `InputLabelPageObject` from `InputLabelVerifications`, which returns an ElementFinder... it does NOT return a string as is needed. In InputLabelPageObject, I added the following line: `getText: function() { this.getLabel().getText(); }`, and then called the `getText()` function in the verification object, and all is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer. And now I feel silly. I'll post as the answer when I can in 2 days. (This only took me several days to get it right.)

Essentially, I'm calling `.getLabel()` from the `InputLabelPageObject` from `InputLabelVerifications`, which returns an `ElementFinder`... it does **not** return a string as is needed. (oops)

In InputLabelPageObject, I added the following line:

```
getText: function() { 
    this.getLabel().getText(); 
}
```

and then called that function in the `InputLabelVerifications` class,

```
verifyText: function (expected) {
    //console.log('Asserting text [' + expected + ']');
    expect(inputLabelPageObject.getText()).toEqual(expected);
},
```

and all is working as expected.